# Copy file from Computer to Android Phone

Tags: android, adb, file-copying

I try to copy file from my PC to Phone but it gets IOException error.
I have written the following code for this task:

Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("adb pull mnt/sdcard/Samsung/Music/test.mp3 E:/");

Comment: Why arent you running `adb` on the PC?

Answer (score 1):

There can be two reasons:

1. You may not have the permission to access that file.
2. You working directory doesn't have access to `adb`. Try running the command as:

   "`cmd /c /pathtoadb/adb.exe pull /pathtofile e:/tryadifferentdirectory/`"

Answer (score 0):

You can also push a file into device using DDMS tool in eclipse. Select mnt/sdcard from file explorer and then click on push file button.